# Option select working only for one dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 columns attendants action and task status in my table as shown below [image]

When i click on allocate it should change to allocated and cancel should change to pending.

I have written jquery for that but it is affecting to only one row and not working for remaining.

**My jquery**

```
$("#stat").on('change', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if($(this).val() == "allocate")
{
    $("#status").val("Allocated");
    $(".hover").css({ 'color': 'green' });
}else if($(this).val() == "cancel"){
    $("#status").val("pending");
    $(".hover").css({ 'color': 'red' });
}
});
```

**My html**

```
<td id="s3">

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>

                    <select style="width: 150px;" class="blue" id="stat" data-style="btn-warning" name="stat">

                        <option value="allocate" id="<?php echo $emp["id"]; ?>" <?php echo (!empty($emp["stat"]) && $emp["stat"] == 'allocate') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>allocate</option>

                        <option value="cancel" id="<?php echo $emp["id"]; ?>" <?php echo (!empty($emp["stat"]) && $emp["stat"] == 'cancel') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>cancel</option>
                    </select>

                </td>  

                <td id="s4">
                    <select style="width: 150px;" class="blue" id="status" data-style="btn-primary" name="status">

                        <option value="pending" <?php echo (!empty($emp["stat"]) && $emp["stat"] == 'cancel') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Pending</option>

                        <option value="Allocated" <?php echo (!empty($emp["stat"]) && $emp["stat"] == 'allocate') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Allocated</option>
                        <option value="Engaged">Engaged</option>
                    </select>

                </td>
```

Comment: Identifiers in HTML must be __unique__, Use Class Selector to bind event handler. And __Share the HTML__ not screenshot

Comment: You'll have to post the html structure of that part of the page for anyone to be able to answer this properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your table rows are dynamic. You can try this if it works.

```js
$("document").on('change', "#stat", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if($(this).val() == "allocate")
{
    $("#status").val("Allocated");
    $(".hover").css({ 'color': 'green' });
}
else if($(this).val() == "cancel")
{
    $("#status").val("pending");
    $(".hover").css({ 'color': 'red' });
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign common CSS class i.e. `stat` and `status` to the `<select>` element's

```
<td> 
    <select class="blue stat">
    </select> 
 </td>
<td>
     <select  class="blue status">
    </select> 
</td>
```

then using Class Selector to bind event handler using it, Use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up-to a common parent then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the desired element

```
$(".stat").on('change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var statusSelect = $(this).closest('tr').find('select.status');
    if ($(this).val() == "allocate") {
        statusSelect.val("Allocated");
        $(".hover").css({
            'color': 'green'
        });
    } else if ($(this).val() == "cancel") {
        statusSelect.val("pending");
        $(".hover").css({
            'color': 'red'
        });
    }
});
```